# Can I have two different student visas with two different EU countries at the same time?

Tags: germany, eu, austria

Can I have two different student visas with two different EU countries (Austria and Germany) at the same time?

I meant, studying in 2 different countries, 2 different courses, for longer, like 1 year. If I have already 1 student visa, in one country, is it possible to take 2nd one in the other country, cause I need flat in both of them?!

Answer (score 4):

Probably my answer becomes too late, but this is a great question, so:

I would suggest that you do not even need two residence permits, rather you can study in both countries under one residence permit, if you satisfy the specific requirements of the [European directive on researchers and students](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=OJ%3AJOL_2016_132_R_0002), which allows you to live and study in multiple EU countries while holding a single residence permit.

More info about it (in German):

- https://www.daad.de/medien/veranstaltungen/lt/2018/plenum_bamf_vortrag_leitertagung_daad_final.pdf
- https://www.uni-hamburg.de/piasta/beratung/2017-08-informationen-fuer-auslaendische-studierende.pdf (see page 20 / 16 according to the Contents)

P.S. I'm not a lawyer.