# Extend staying in another EU country more than 6 months for internship with Germany student residence permit

Tags: germany, resident-permit, student-visa, internship

I hold a Germany student residence permit **(Aufenthaltstitel- I’m a Non-EU citizen)** and if I leave Germany more than 6 months my visa will be invalid. My situation is that I am in Hungary for my exchange program internship (I got a Hungarian residence permit for that) and after a period of 6 months, the company and I would like to extend my internship for another 6 months. So I want to ask that, is there a **certificate (fiktionsbescheinigung) to grant permission** for student like me to extend my stay in another Europe country? Or can I return to Germany for 1-2 months and come back to Hungary to continue my internship to **keep my student visa valid**?

P/s: To be more clear, I still enrolled in my university the whole internship period. I still have my health insurance and I have my dormitory sublet to another student with approval from the university

I really don’t want to give up on this opportunity to continue the internship so I’m very appreciated if you have some idea to help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if your situation satisfies European directive for researchers and students, please see [my another answer on this](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19262/13223).

If you do not fit into that regulation, then I would expect that you need to apply for a residence permit in Hungary (probably, one is not allowed to stay there longer than 6 months with student residence permit of another country).

In order to avoid the expiration of your German residence permit, you should then contact Ausländerbehörde in Germany, they can probably make an exception for you.

P.S. I'm not a lawyer, and for you it might be a good idea to get a professional advice. Maybe, as a starting point, you can try to ask people in the international office of your university for further information.